# How to convert " get (gcf, 'currentchar') ~= ' ' " from Matlab to Python?

Tags: python, matlab

I'm trying to convert a Matlab program into Python.
This is the beginning of the Matlab code :

```
while get(gcf, 'currentchar') ~= ' '
    if get(gcf,'currentchar')=='r'
```

I've seen that I need to import matplotlib.pyplot which I did, but I failed to find an equivalent of the Matlab 'currentchar' in Python. Same thing for the "get" part.
I'm guessing the goal of the Matlab program is to detect which key is used when the current figure is opened and act accordingly (when a key is used, if the used key is "r", then do [...])

Would you have any idea of how to translate this?

Comment: No need to guess what this does in MATLAB - it's [documented](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html#buiwuyk-1-CurrentCharacter).

Comment: Thank you for the link. I found a module called "getkey" that seemed to do what I want, but the code I wrote leads to an infinite loop even after I press 'r' or 'n'.
Here is the code:
`import getkey /
from getkey import getkey, keys /
//
key = getkey() /
while key != ' ': /
    if key == 'r' : /
        print('Reset.') /
    if key == 'n' : /
        print 'New lens created'`

Any ideas?